# Anaconda Navigator gone after downgrading PyQt?

Tags: anaconda

I changed the version of PyQt from 5.6.0 to 4.1.1 through the Anaconda Navigator window and now the Anaconda Navigator as well as the spyder are gone from the start menu. I don't know how to open them. Any tips? I'm very inexperienced with this so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm on Windows 8.1 and using Anaconda 4.2.0